# What is the best approach to learning hardware design?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, c, embedded, hardware

I am a self taught software developer who has recently become interested in embedded systems. I am interested in learning how to design PCBs and learn about the electrical components the PCBs house. I have no idea where to start as I have no prior experience in hardware design. Is this a subject that I can teach myself or should I take courses?

My ideal goal is to be able to design a PCB from schematic to layout, design the complete device/gadget, and develop the firmware for the device. Then I would proceed to get the PCB fabricated and manufactured. After, I would continue to have the entire device assembled for production/release. I have a lot of gadget and device concepts so I am very excited about this journey.

Any advice or guidance in the right direction is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Start by reading *The Art of Electronics* by Horowitz and Hill, it's a great introduction to electronics. Then start playing around with LTspice and KiCAD.

Comment: Attend technical courses in the evenings with a lab component leading to a 1-2 year technical diploma at your community college. Meet a counsellor. This is different from learning software as an initial investment is required in tools, equipment and perhaps some workshop like space. All this does not obviate the need for a lot of expert help especially in the beginning. For software, googling leads to answers whereas in this field, it may only lead to suggestions.

Comment: Start building things ,Always try to fix things.

Comment: It's a huge topic so the most sensible route is to get an electrical engineering degree. Sure you can learn a lot yourself, but you may end up with knowledge gaps and misunderstandings.

Comment: Get a cheap DMM, a few resistors and LEDs, a battery, and start building, blowing components up and working out why. I've never yet had an electronics design where I didn't learn something after building something, even if it wasn't the thing I'd hoped to learn. Then get a simulator, LTSpice or Microcap, and play with that. Ping between real circuits and a simulator until you're happy with trusting each for the unique features that they bring.

Comment: As opposed to those who say: read "The Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill" I would say: don't read it **yet**. Maybe just browse through it and see what is there. Start building something and it doesn't need (actually: should not) be something complicated. Look on instructables.com and see what you like and build the same or something similar. Work your way up to more complicated things. Look at lots of circuit designs online and in magazines, then realize: hey I saw that in The Art of Electronics, **then** read that section.

Comment: To me, an attempt at mastery is one of the goals. I am a software developer like you, and I chose a similar path. My road in was the [Joule Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief), which I started building many of, and experimenting, and reading incessantly. I ordered an older version of Art of Electronics because I was mainly interested in the analog parts, which haven't changed that much, and the older book was much less expensive. I eventually got the latest version in Kindle, so I can do a word search, which is great. The books you will want are expensive, though, many are >$100

Comment: I found that the LTSpice circuit simulator was free, and simulated Joule Thief circuits very well (and fast). I learned how to .step my values and optimized many circuits in LTSpice. It's so fast, much progress on certain fronts can be made very quickly.

Comment: Once you've got a lot of the details worked out, build it, and then you can come here when it doesn't work because you weren't aware of the parasitics (resistance, capacitance, inductance, impedance, that all pop up in crazy places because you didn't realize that capacitors also have inductance and resistance, and inductors also have capacitance and resistance, etc. )

Comment: So, to sum up, I think that learning a lot to a shallow level, is complemented well by doing a deep learning on just one or two subjects, to build your knowledge foundation. Other good first topics are electronic synthesizer music, along with analog amplifier design, and also [Ham Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) is very good to start out with, and is very interesting, with a lot of good learning materials that can be easily found, and a community to help. A friend of mine started with mechatronics for Christmas displays. Another started with Radio-Controlled airplane

Answer (score 4):

To me personally, books and theoretical essays are only useful *after* I have already established some profound understanding of a topic.

If you are starting from scratch, look for a *specific* problem you *must* solve. Then do some research on how to achieve it. This is the best way (to me anyway) to actually retain the learnt knowledge. Today there is massive amounts of quality free content on youtube (besides an even massiver amount of garbage) but also several good written electronics blogs and whitepapers give great specific explanations without wasting days of your time.

Then solve new problems and so on, ideally you can iterate from your previous results. And when you believe that you have gathered some experience, then you go on read a comprehensive book. This can help to coalesce your patchy practical knowledge into a deeper generalist picture.